# Unable to mount NTFS partition using ntfs-3g

Tags: linux, mount, ntfs, ntfs-3g

My system was able to mount NTFS partitions previosly, but after some while, mounting "broke" and cannot succeed now. Details:

- Disks are healthy, I checked the system on 3 different disks.
- Attempt to mount the disk gives the following error:

  ```
  # ntfs-3g /dev/sdc1 /mnt/deleteme/
  mount: according to mtab, /dev/sdc1 is already mounted on /mnt/deleteme
  ```
- mtab does not have any relevant entries:

  ```
  /dev/sda7 /home ext4 rw 0 0
  binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
  systemd /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd cgroup rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd 0 0
  ```
- fstab does not have any relevant entries.
- If I remove the `ntfs-3g` package, the system is able to mount the partition in read-only mode. I think this is because of the kernel built-in support for NTFS (in `ro` mode).

Other things which may or may not be relevant (sorry..):

- somewhy tty1 "stops loading" at boot, it remains with the text "Loading, please wait...".  Other tty-s work correctly. (Again, may not be relevant.)
- my main system is ubuntu-14.04LTS, but I have some foreign repositories included, too. The "/etc/apt/preferences.d" seems to be set up correctly, with only minimal allowance for foreign repos. But I can't be 100% sure. `apt-cache policy ntfs-3g` and all its dependencies show only the official ubuntu repository.

I want to understand the reasons or at least fix the current situation.. Hoping for any kinds of answers/questions, thanks.

Comment: The accepted thing to do, having found your own solution, is to post it as an answer and accept that. It's entirely acceptable to accept your own answer.

Comment: Shiny. That will make it easier for anyone else with the same problem (because they can choose to search only questions with accepted answers, to help narrow things down, and now this question will show up in such a search).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdc1
sudo mount.ntfs-3g /dev/sdc1 /mnt/deleteme/
```

Ref. [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1607680&p=10037881#post10037881)

Comment: this simply does NOT work. If it would work, I would not write the question... The system does not allow me to mount any NTFS partitions even after reboot. Other types of partitions work OK.

Comment: Please sudo `blkid` command with that partition as argument, and see if you can see UUID on `/etc/fstab` or as output of plain `mount`. Also post result of `udisks --dump`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'm having a very strange history with ntfs3g. I noticed that my system gives some warnings about cryptsetup (ecryptfs) mapping during boot. I removed all corresponding these packages from my system and did a reboot. Coincidence or not, the ntfs3g disks started to mount normally.

Comment: I'm very sorry for this story overall: not really a good question description, slow communication and finally a not well-defined solution. Hope at least it didn't take much time.. And thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by removing all ecryptfs-related packages, namely `cryptsetup` and `ecryptfs-tools`.

These are packages for encrypted filesystems above normal partitions. I previously had them used above my /home `ext4` partition, and it seems I didn't remove everything throughly and properly. Incorrect data was left, and it gave warnings at boot time (incorrect mappings for ecryptfs).

It seems like, while attempting to mount these encrypted filesystems, the system got an error and was not able to mount ntfs3g partitions after that. (It's kinda strange, because ntfs3g should not be related to ecryptfs above ext4, but that's what happened on my system.)